# Update Dynamically Added Select Fields

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, crud

How to update dynamically added select fields created in Jquery?

I have a sports website, with a specific page that generates dynamic dependent dropdown menus. They are all coded in via Jquery via onclick function. So when user clicks on a button called "Add", it will create one row containing all three select fields where users can select the different dropdown options. User can add or remove as many rows as they wish.

There are three dropdowns total. First one generates data from table A called 'team', and the other two options generate data from table B called 'players'. Option 2 & 3 are dependent on option 1.

So for exmaple - if user selects 'Montreal' for option 1, then option 2/3 will show only Montreal players. If user selects 'Boston' for option 1, then option 2/3 will show only Boston players.

This works perfectly and after clicking submit, all the rows are submitted to my database. What I am trying to do now is somehow edit/update these dynamically created rows

Here is a snippet of some of my jquery code that creates the dropdown divs. I can show all my PHP work as well if need be:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var count = 0;
      $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_category[]" data-sub_category_id="'+count+'" ><option value="">Select Category</option><?php echo fill_select_box($connect, "0"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_sub_category[]"           id="item_sub_category'+count+'"><option                   value="">Select Sub Category</option></select>            </td>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_name[]" id="item_name'+count+'"><option value="">Select SubSub Category</option></select></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="remove"><span>REMOVE</span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
      });
```

The 'echo fill_select_box' part is a PHP function i made in a separate page. So it is using that function to get data from database. And then after clicked, Ajax kicks in and populates the other dropdown options.

First off, is there a better way to add dynamic select fields besides using jquery? If this is the only way to do it then that's cool.

If this is the way to do it, does anyone have any references or resources they can point me to? I have found very LITTLE  online in regards to this specific task (updating dynamic select fields that were created via jquery). I am even debating buying Jon Duckett's PHP book in hopes that it will help me figure this out on my own.

I'm just lost in the sauce and feel like i hit a wall. Genuinely want to understand how i can tackle this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: `is there a better way to add dynamic select fields besides using jquery`...how are you defining "better"? Are you having any issues right now? You mention a "problem", but it's actually very unclear specifically what the problem is. It there something not working as you wish in your code?

Comment: Your question contains quite a lot of text and little code. The code that is there makes little sense. You're adding three menus with one option to a table? Why?

Comment: One of the basic building blocks in JavaScript is the [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions). You can improve your code by using it. For instance, you create a table cell with a menu three times, and you write the full code for that three time. You only need to do that once if you use a function.